# How to get/generate the create statement for an existing hive table?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Assuming you have "table" already in Hive, is there a quick way like other databases to be able to get the "CREATE" statement for that table?

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE 'Table_Name';

Answer (score 239, accepted):

[As of Hive 0.10](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-ddl.html#LanguageManualDDL-ShowCreateTable) this [patch-967](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-967) implements `SHOW CREATE TABLE` which "shows the `CREATE TABLE` statement that creates a given table, or the `CREATE VIEW` statement that creates a given view."

Usage:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable;
```

Answer (score 34):

Steps to generate Create table DDLs for all the tables in the Hive database and export into text file to run later:

***step 1)***
create a `.sh` file with the below content, say `hive_table_ddl.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f tableNames.txt
rm -f HiveTableDDL.txt
hive -e "use $1; show tables;" > tableNames.txt  
wait
cat tableNames.txt |while read LINE
   do
   hive -e "use $1;show create table $LINE;" >>HiveTableDDL.txt
   echo  -e "\n" >> HiveTableDDL.txt
   done
rm -f tableNames.txt
echo "Table DDL generated"
```

***step 2)***

Run the above shell script by passing 'db name' as paramanter

```
>bash hive_table_dd.sh <<databasename>>
```

output :

All the create table statements of your DB will be written into the `HiveTableDDL.txt`

Comment: how we could make sure that the buckets and storage format will going to be replicate into new table.

Comment: You should also append a semicolon after each statement so that the script can be executed by saying hive -f HiveTableDDL.txt.

Comment: This script is failing for me with the below error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:18 cannot recognize input near '|' '|' in table name

I am executing this script with beeline as HDP 3.0 does not support hive-shell access

Comment: @cfeduke this script gives the location of hive tables. how to skip location part inorder to run these  ddls in another hive location ? alter on more than 1000 tables is not possible

Answer (score 2):

Describe Formatted/Extended will show the data definition of the table in hive

```
hive> describe Formatted dbname.tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# !/bin/bash 
for DB in `beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "show databases;"` 
do
for Tab in `beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "use $DB; show tables;"` 
do 
beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "show create table $DB.$Tab;" >$DB.$Tab.hql
done
done
```

Comment: this code will give you all tables DDL from all databases

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).